# How to solve this error "Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2"?

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012, devexpress, windows-server-2008

I am trying to deploy my site on my own server (Windows server 2008 R2) on IIS.

At first it throws target framework configuration error. Then I installed **.Net Framework 4.5**, **After I installed  .Net Framework 4.5**, not it throws the following error

> Configuration Error 
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 35:     
>   Line 36:       
>   Line 37:         
>   Line 38:         
>   Line 39:
>
> Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwReport\web.config    Line: 37
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2, Version=15.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
>   To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
>   Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
>   To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

After I google it, I created Enable Log 1 on fusion too in this way.

1. open **cmd on Administrator**
2. run the cmd **"reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion /v EnableLog /t REG_DWORD /d 1"**

3.**"Operation completed successfully"**

Comment: you need to add a reference to `DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2.dll` into your project, then rebuild and deploy again.

Comment: @andrews I tried the same files with my local machine. It was worked fine. But why not in my server?.

Comment: because on the server the mention .dll is simply missing in the bin folder of your app. Check if the `DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2.dll` file exists in the `bin/` folder on server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To resolve this issue actually you have build project by enabling the property Copy to Local=true,
then you will get that assembly and you have to put  DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.v15.2 in bin folder where u deployed that specific project that is (Windows server 2008 R2)

Comment: Can you tell me how to enable the property copy to Local = true?

Answer (score -1):

You can follow these steps to enable the property Copy Local:

1. Right Click your mouse on the DLL file.
2. In the properties windows, you can see; Copy Local and on the other cell change the value from False to True.